# Redirecting from child IFRAME to parent IFRAME not working in FIREFOX using _parent target

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, firefox, iframe

In my case, I have 3 IFRAMES (A, B, and C). And hierarchy is C inside B and B inside A. So, my problem I'm unable to redirect to B from C in firefox. And the same working in chrome.

Trying so hard for a solution appreciate any help on this.

Parent IFRAME

```
<h1>Inside Parent page</h1>
<iframe src='child1.html' width='1000' height='1000' name='parent-iframe'><iframe>
```

Child1 IFRAME

```
<h1>Inside Child-1 page</h1>
<iframe src='child2.html' width='1000' height='1000' name='child-iframe'><iframe>
```

Child2 IFRAME

```
<h1>Inside Child-2 IFRAME</h1>
<button onclick='accessParent()'>Submit</button>
<a href="final.html" id="parent-redirect" target="_parent"></a>
<a href="final.html" id="top-redirect" target="_top"></a>
<script>
    function accessParent(){
        document.getElementById('parent-redirect').click();
        //document.getElementById('top-redirect').click();
    }
</script>
```

Final page

```
<h1>Inside Final page</h1>
```

Comment: Check the Developer Console of your Browser and see, which error messages are displayed

Comment: Don't see any errors when clicked the submit button.

Comment: Does it also not work, if you actually click the link yourself? Or is it just in combination with trying to click that link _via_ JavaScript?

Comment: The Problem here is that the JavaScript 'click' event is not trusted by the Browser. I think Firefox refuses to follow a link in with a target in another frame for security reasons

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted